# Excel: Format Color of A Group of Rows Based on the Maximum Value of these Rows

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, vba

I have the following problem. Given the data:

City Begin

1 2000-01-01

1 2002-02-01

1 2002-02-01

2 2002-02-01

2 2003-02-01

2 2005-12-01

3 2002-04-01

3 2003-07-01

3 2005-12-01

I wanted to group rows by the city they belong to. For each group, I wanted to color all rows in that group red if the maximum date in that group does not equal 2005-12-01, and blue if otherwise. In the sample data, this means that all rows with city 1 is colored red, and those with cities 2 and 3 are blue.

Is there a way to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non-VBA method:

- Conditional formatting -> New Rule...
- Select "Format all cells based on thier values"
- Format Style = "2-Color Scale"
- Colors = [As needed]

[image]

VBA method:

```
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A10") 'or where-ever.
With rng.FormatConditions
    .AddColorScale 2
    With .Item(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1)
        .Type = xlConditionValueLowestValue
        .FormatColor.Color = 15773696
    End With
    With .Item(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2)
        .Type = xlConditionValueHighestValue
        .FormatColor.Color = 255
    End With
End With
```

EDIT: It's late, so after reading the question again I may have got the colors reversed... Emphasis on "As needed".